# In a WebAPI Formatter, how can you get the URL from HttpContent?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In a WebAPI service, we are using a Formatter to read a content parameter on a request.  We need access to the URL in order to transform the content parameter correctly.  HttpRequestMessage isn't available, and we can't use HttpContext.Current.Request because HttpContext.Current is null.  Accessing the HttpRequestMessage on a Read was requested at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/82, but this issue was closed because HttpContent is available on a Read.  However, I don't know how to get the URL from HttpContent, or even if it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

There is a method called GetPerRequestFormatterInstance on the formatter which you can override to create a new instance of the formatter with the stateful information about the request in it. By the way, this method GetPerRequestFormatterInstance is only called during the request's deserialization stage. Example below:

```
public class TextPlainFormatter : BufferedMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public TextPlainFormatter()
    {
        this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
    }

    public HttpRequestMessage CurrentRequest
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public override MediaTypeFormatter GetPerRequestFormatterInstance(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
    {
        TextPlainFormatter frmtr = new TextPlainFormatter();
        frmtr.CurrentRequest = request;

        //Copy from the original formatter instance to the new instance
        frmtr.MediaTypeMappings.Clear();
        foreach (MediaTypeMapping mediaTypeMapping in this.MediaTypeMappings)
        {
            frmtr.MediaTypeMappings.Add(mediaTypeMapping);
        }

        frmtr.RequiredMemberSelector = this.RequiredMemberSelector;

        frmtr.SupportedEncodings.Clear();
        foreach (Encoding supportedEncoding in this.SupportedEncodings)
        {
            frmtr.SupportedEncodings.Add(supportedEncoding);
        }

        frmtr.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
        foreach (MediaTypeHeaderValue supportedMediaType in this.SupportedMediaTypes)
        {
            frmtr.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(supportedMediaType);
        }

        return frmtr;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  This technique works if your formatter is being used on the outgoing response, but unfortunately it does not work if your formatter is being used on the incoming request.

Comment: Actually Web API's runtime calls GetPerRequestFormatterInstance method on an incoming request(deserialization) as I mentioned in the above post.

Comment: I think the formatter instance is common to all requests, so doesn't this suffer from huge concurrency issues? Say you have 2 incoming requests nearly at the same time (both received before any response has been serialized), which request will be set in the CurrentRequest property?